# ios - error while archiving a new app. Code Sign error: No unexpired

Tags: ios, ios6

I got this error while archiving:

```
Code Sign error: No unexpired provisioning profiles found that contain any of the keychain's signing certificates
```

I do have a certificate which I have used before. And I am trying to reuse it, but not sure how.  And I am not sure if that is the issue.  I made sure that the AppId is the same in xCode and the ios Developer portal.

But I did not create provisioning or distribution certificates for the new app since I wanted to use my existing ones from the previous apps.  Did I confuse some of the concepts? Possibly I am mixing up the roles of the Keychain access key, and the provisioning+distribution files.

If anyone could point out a fix, that would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: Run the "KeyChain access" app (under Utilities) on your Mac. Did your distribution certificate expire?

Comment: Expired profiles should also be displayed in XCode's Organizer window.

Comment: If the certificate is fine, it appears your provisioning profiles have expired. Look in the Xcode Organizer. Select the Devices tab then select Provisioning Profiles on left.

Comment: @rmaddy is has not expired.  What do I do once I run that app?

Comment: Nothing. Once you know the certificate is fine, follow my previous comment for checking the provisioning profiles. If they are expired you need to renew them.

Comment: @rmaddy are the provisioning files the ones I have to make in the developer portal?  I have not made them individually for this app.  Should I make them? Or can I reuse existing ones?

Comment: You need to setup an App Id, then new provisioning profiles. Do all of this in the Developer Portal. Make sure the App Id matches your Bundle Id in the Info.plist. All of this is documented by Apple.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks! I did make the AppId. Just so I am clear, I need to go to the provisioning and distribution tabs and make new entries for this app, right?

Comment: @rmaddy Alo, what should be the profile name when I make the new entries? Is it arbitrary? Or I have to get that exactly matching something else?  Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, you need to make development and distribution provisioning profiles with the new app id.

Comment: @rmaddy Ok so I just created the provisioning entries for distribution and development. But then when I tried to archive from my xCode, I got the same error. Did I not do some step?

Comment: Did you download the new profiles, install them into Xcode, and update your project to use them? Please read the docs.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, I downloaded and installed the files. The only thing I am not sure how to do is what do I do to configure the files that I installed inside xCode?